# Generic shell/bash method to parse string for possibly quoted fields?

Tags: string, bash, parsing, textfield

While coding munin scripts I often have to parse configuration files looking for some path.

The problem with configuration files without strong markup (ie. not XML) is theses paths can have multiple syntaxes:

- Single-quoted (') or double-quoted (") or unquoted
- Containing spaces (escaped if string is unquoted)
- Containing quotes (usually it's single quote)

For example I'm looking for a way to parse the following lines in order to extract the path (which is, this time, in first position):

```
/mnt/DirWithoutSpaces/ "Dir1" cnidscheme:dbd perm:0775 options:usedots,upriv
/mnt/Dir\ With\ Space/ Dir2 cnidscheme:dbd options:usedots,upriv
"/mnt/Dir With Space And D-quote" Dir3
'/mnt/Dir With Space And S-quote' Dir4
~/ "Dir 5" cnidscheme:dbd
"/mnt/Dir'ed" "Dir 6" cnidscheme:dbd
```

I usually go with `ERE` and `=~` bash operator (`[[ $string =~ $pattern ]]`) but each time it's a real pain in the head.

I'm pretty sure that any of variable mangling, `cut`, `awk`, `sed` can be very helpful and automatically deal with quotes and other stuff but I can't find that special magical recipe.

Comment: Is using `flex` really out of the question?

Comment: Never used flex but it can be somehow included/called from an sh/bash/perl/python/php script I can't see any reason not to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `-P (--perl-regexp)` option in `grep`:

```
$ grep -oP "^(\\\\ |[^ '\"])*" input.txt
/mnt/DirWithoutSpaces/
/mnt/Dir\ With\ Space/
~/

$ grep -oP "^(['\"]).*?\1" input.txt
"/mnt/Dir With Space And D-quote"
'/mnt/Dir With Space And S-quote'
"/mnt/Dir'ed"
```

---

```
$ grep -oP "^(['\"]).*?\1|^(\\\\ |[^ '\"])*" input.txt
/mnt/DirWithoutSpaces/
/mnt/Dir\ With\ Space/
"/mnt/Dir With Space And D-quote"
'/mnt/Dir With Space And S-quote'
~/
"/mnt/Dir'ed"
```

Comment: I was looking for a more generic way to find/detect paths in a string.

Comment: That's the beauty and horror of regexp, right there -- those patterns found the exact pieces you're interested in finding, but validating their correctness is .. difficult, at best. :)

Comment: Accepting your answer because it actually helped me but still looking forward of a generic pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a couple native bash functions to do this: https://github.com/mblais/bash_ParseFields

You can use the `ParseFields` function like this:

```
$ str='field1 field\ 2 "field 3"'
$ ParseFields -d "$str" a b c d
$ printf "|%s|\n|%s|\n|%s|\n|%s|\n" "$a" "$b" "$c" "$d"
|field1|         
|field 2|
|field 3|
||
```

The `-d` option to ParseFields removes any surrounding quotes and interprets backslashes from the parsed fields.

There is also a simpler `ParseField` function (used by `ParseFields`) that parses a single field at a specific offset within a string.

Note that these functions cannot parse a *stream*, only a string. The IFS variable can also be used to specify field delimiters besides whitespace.

If you require that unescaped apostrophes may appear in *unquoted* fields, that would require a minor change - let me know.

Comment: Again: answers that consist of little more than links are discouraged here. Please consider expanding on your answer to include some concrete examples. Also, be careful submitting (nearly) identical answers to multiple questions. It's a good way for the system to automatically flag your content as spam.